# Magento API Report place order Error: Uncaught TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, datetime

When i tried to place an order there is an api error report error that saying:

```
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in \/var\/www\/M2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Stdlib\/DateTime.php:58
```

**vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime.php:58**

```
...
} elseif (!is_numeric($date)) {
   $date = (new \DateTime($date))->getTimestamp();
}
...
```

i tried to `var_dump` the `$date` variable, here's the result:

```
string(37) "Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor"
```

i tried to `debug_backtrace` , here's the result:

```
Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime->formatDate
Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->formatDate
Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->prepareColumnValue
Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->_prepareDataForTable
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\EntityAbstract->_prepareDataForSave
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\EntityAbstract->saveNewObject
Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order->save
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository->save
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor->___callParent
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins
Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor->save
Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService->place
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callParent
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->submit
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->placeOrder
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callParent
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
Magento\Braintree\Plugin\OrderCancellation->aroundPlaceOrder
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->placeOrder
Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder
Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent
Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins
Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder
call_user_func_array
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch
Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch
Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run
```

Comment: Have you modified this file at all?

Comment: @NSwanson7 not at all

Comment: is this a vanilla Magento 2 instance?

Comment: Go to `Step 2: How to Setup PHP options` and verify you've configured `date.timezone` in your php.ini. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

Comment: @NSwanson7 no, i downloaded it from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Comment: @NSwanson7 my date.timezon in php.ini is commented, what should I filled it with?

Comment: By vanilla I mean have you modified any files in the code base after installation? I'm assuming you installed Magento 2 using composer? Is this correct?

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: @NSwanson7 i add some custom extension, UTC+7

Comment: Can you provide me with a country and the nearest large city you like to set the time zone to.

Comment: @NSwanson7 Bangkok thailand

Comment: Set your `date.timezone="Asia/Bangkok"`. If you're using php-fpm you'll need to restart it. Depending on what OS you're using the command to restart it will vary. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @NSwanson7 done, im using ubuntu with apache2, but the error still exists

Comment: Do any of the custom extensions you installed deal with orders, quotes, carts, or customers?